# Submit not working in Chrome and IE under Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have a web form created using .net and in this form has a frame which has its source from another HTML page (created by courselab software). I call a javascript code whenever the user completes the page and click a submit button and exits normally or whenever the user navigates away from the page based on the javascript event "onbeforeunload".

The code works just perfectly using

**Firefox in both cases**
**IE on Windows XP in both cases**

Still it works in **CHROME** if the user clicked on the submit button (this submit button generated by courselab software which calls the javascript code),

but if the user navigates away from the web form, this code is being called using the "onbeforeunload" and the code renders correctly but the submit input is never fired.

**Similary this code does not fire using IE on Windows 7.**

I have also called the code "onunload" of the form, but still nothing happens.

**Update**
IE 8 
Firefox 3.6.1.3
Chrome 9.0.597.98

the main web form has the following

```
<div id="FOContent">
<iframe  runat=server id="mainiframe" name="mainiframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"
width="1000" height="920"></iframe>
</div>
```

The frame content comes from this HTML page

```
<body style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;"  onload="Run(true)" onunload="Shutdown()" onbeforeunload="Shutdown()" oncontextmenu="return false">
<div id="boardFrame" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:1000;height:700">
</div>
<div id="divEmail"></div>
</body>
```

And the javascript code being called for "onunload" or "onbeforeunload" is

```
function LMSShutdown() {
if (submit_Var == false) {
    var sAiccData = AICC_PrepareData();  // prepare data from the CourseLab
    var strQuizResults
    strQuizResults = "";
    var nPos1 = sAiccData.indexOf("Score=");
    nPos1 = nPos1 + 6;
    var ePos1 = nPos1 + 2
    var score = sAiccData.substring(nPos1, ePos1);

    var sHTML = "";
    var qTxt;
    qTxt = ""

    var qrStr = window.location.search;
    var spQrStr = qrStr.substring(1);
    var arrQrStr = new Array();
    // splits each of pair
    var arr = spQrStr.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // splits each of field-value pair
        var index = arr[i].indexOf("=");
        var key = arr[i].substring(0, index);
        var val = arr[i].substring(index + 1);
        var id1
        var id2
        if (key == "")
            {key = "Q"+i}
        qTxt = qTxt + "&" + key + "=" + val;
        if (i == 0)
        { id1 = val; }
        else
        { id2 = val; }
}
// saves each of field-value pair in an array variable
sHTML += '<FORM id="formQuiz" method="POST" action="../../../StudentView/QuizProcess.aspx?submit_Var=' + 'false' + '&score=' + score + qTxt + '">';
var spQrStr = g_arVars["writing"];
var arrQrStr = new Array();
// splits each of pair
var arr = spQrStr.split("@@@");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
// splits each of field-value pair
var index = arr[i].lastIndexOf(":");
var key = arr[i].substring(0, index);
var val = arr[i].substring(index + 1);
if (key != "")
{qTxt = qTxt + "&" + key + "=" + val;
sHTML += '<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="' + key + '" VALUE=\'' + val + '\'>';
}
}
sHTML += '<br><input name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" type="button"><br>';
sHTML += '</FORM>';
document.getElementById("divEmail").innerHTML = sHTML;
document.getElementById("formQuiz").submit();
submit_Var = true;
}
}
```

The QuizProcess.aspx page has not much in HTML, but it has vb .net code to store data to database

The issue is that the function LMSShutdown is being called in all browsers on different platforms, but the form QuizProcess is not being submitted only in (chrome on Windows XP or 7 ) and in (IE 8 when using Windows 7) strangely works fine in IE 8 on Windows XP.

Comment: Hi user616912 and welcome to StackOverflow! I know someone here would love to help you answer your question, but, in order to help you, we'll need more information. First, you did not specify the browser version of the various situations (IE6/7/8? Firefox v???). In addition, it would greatly help if you could include the code that you are discussing (at least, the important parts). All this will help us better help you. Use the edit button your post to update it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Please provide some source code so we can have a look at what your doing.  It's hard to help when you might be missing a ; and we can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/00b88378-a7f1-4148-9587-1ff17d6fa728

Essentially it seems that in Windows 7 and also in IE9, a child form is denied access to the submit call.

The trick is to get the parent to do the call.  Put the onbeforeunload event on the parent form and it find the frame and from there the form and it is allowed to call the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Check, or disable your extensions, and see which one it is. I had it with AdBlock happen before.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the required code to explain the problem, can I expect some help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you install the FireBug extension for Chrome and when you run it, check for errors on your page.